# How to do SUM() but with some rules to follow?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Maybe this question is confusing to understand ( as I'm not fluent in English ) but,
I need to select `sum(cod)` for example, but this `sum()` needs to have the following rule:

Part 1:
it needs to be ALL cods, except for `21`.

Part2:
Another column, with another `sum()`, but only with cod 21.

it's not the entire query, But after this, I think I can do it.

I tried this:

```
select sum(vit_codigotiposexames) from 
    (
    select * from tb_vitima where vit_codigotiposexames  
        in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,22 )
    )Corpo_Delito,
sum(vit_codigotiposexames) from
    (
    select * from tb_vitima where vit_codigotiposexames  = 21 )
    )Cadaverico
```

It works If I have only

```
select sum(vit_codigotiposexames) from 
    (
    select * from tb_vitima where vit_codigotiposexames  
        in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,22 )
    )Corpo_Delito
```

is there a way to make this query, a unique query? and, is there a way to name these columns? because I know I need to alias them, but they stay with that (no column name) above it.

Comment: have you tried with `vit_codigotiposexames  <> 21` or `vit_codigotiposexames  not in (21)`?

Comment: hey @McNets, the problem is, that I need two sums() in the same query, with the same column, but with different rules. it would work with 2 queries.

Comment: Take @McNets suggestion as one to make the query more easily maintainable and readable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you can differentiate this SUM's using a SUM(CASE) statement:

```
select sum(case when vit_codigotiposexames = 21 
                then vit_codigotiposexames 
                else 0 end) Cadaverico,
       sum(case when vit_codigotiposexames <> 21 
                then vit_codigotiposexames 
                else 0 end) CorpoDelito
from   tb_vitima;
```

I've set up an example:

> ```
> create table tb_vitima (id int identity, vit_codigotiposexames int);
> insert into tb_vitima values (2),(5),(10),(11),(21),(21),(10),(23);
>
> select sum(case when vit_codigotiposexames = 21 then vit_codigotiposexames else 0 end) Cadaverico,
>        sum(case when vit_codigotiposexames <> 21 then vit_codigotiposexames else 0 end) CorpoDelito
> from   tb_vitima;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Cadaverico | CorpoDelito
> ---------: | ----------:
>         42 |          61
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7f92ed206cd344195b9c87bce55dfb5f)*

Comment: Oh Nice. I will try this and post results.i'm trying to create temp tables

Comment: Nice one. I think I will stick with it. Thanks, bro. I was trying to do it with pivot, but it's a lot harder than using case.

Comment: In PostgreSQL, you can omit the `ELSE`. A `CASE` where none of the conditions is true gives back `NULL` and `NULL` has no affect on `SUM`. Is SQL Server the same?

Comment: @jpmc26 `ELSE NULL` is the default in all DBMS. Problem is that if all the summed up values are null, `SUM()` does not return `0` but `NULL`. Which is also the SQL default - even if it is mathematically nonsense.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ It does the same thing in the event that there are no rows to aggregate. `ELSE 0` doesn't help with that. `COALESCE(SUM(...), 0)` is a more robust way of dealing with a `NULL` result. If you need to distinguish between no rows to aggregate and no rows matching the `CASE` statement, then I guess the `ELSE 0` could be used for that, but that seems like a rather rare use case.

Comment: @jpmc26 *"It does the same thing in the event that there are no rows to aggregate."* which is inconsistent, too, with the mathematical definition of sum. I find `SUM(CASE WHEN a THEN b ELSE 0 END)`, `COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN a THEN b END), 0)` and `COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN a THEN b ELSE NULL END), 0)` equally readable with a slight preference to the first.

Comment: The only case that we'll get different results is if the table is empty, so you may have a point that COALESCE is strictly needed to avoid that anyway.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Or if a `WHERE` clause filters everything out. I'm not sure I buy the "inconsistent with math" part. Math doesn't (usually?) concern itself with what happens in a sum if there are no operands to add. And even if it did, math typically doesn't work in 3 valued logic. In a SQL engine, where `NULL` more or less means "unknown value," it seems like a logical result for, "You tried to add a bunch of unknowns or nothing at all together." Why should the engine assume that these are equivalent to adding all 0s?

Comment: @jpmc26 I assure that  the sum where there are no oopernads to add is defined in math: it's 0 for integers (or the identity element regarding addition). Regarding inconsistency: tell me why these two queries return different results: `select sum(i) from (values (1), (2), (null)) as x (i);` and `select 1 + 2 + null ;` If NULL is treated as an unknown value, why is it treated differently in these cases?

Answer (score 2):

I realize you've already selected another answer, but I at least wanted to clean up my original offering.

```
select 
    (
    select sum(vit_codigotiposexames) as Corpo_Delito from tb_vitima where vit_codigotiposexames  
        in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,22 )
    ) as Corpo_Delito,
    (
    select sum(vit_codigotiposexames) as Cadaverico from tb_vitima where vit_codigotiposexames  = 21 
    ) as Cadaverico
```

Comment: hey @scott. Yeah, I tried this but it has syntax error because of the `as` and the `,`. Even using the `alias as column_name` I have the same error.

Comment: You really should get rid of that huge `in` list, or the query will return wrong results when someone gets the idea to introduce a new code.

Comment: This would work if your first line didn't have `* from`

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli - I realize you've already accepted another answer (and it's definitely better), but I at least wanted to clean up my original offering which had a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

I heartily recommend McNets' answer. However, I thought I'd try to explain what the problem with your original query was.

That query again (in case it changes as you work through the question):

```
select sum(vit_codigotiposexames) from 
    (
    select * from tb_vitima where vit_codigotiposexames  
        in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,22 )
    )Corpo_Delito,
sum(vit_codigotiposexames) from
    (
    select * from tb_vitima where vit_codigotiposexames  = 21 )
    )Cadaverico
```

Your entire `SELECT` list (the columns to return) must proceed your `FROM` clause, and you can only have one `FROM` clause in a query.

You can break this into two queries:

```
select sum(vit_codigotiposexames) from 
    (
    select * from tb_vitima where vit_codigotiposexames  
        in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,22 )
    )Corpo_Delito
;
select sum(vit_codigotiposexames) from
    (
    select * from tb_vitima where vit_codigotiposexames  = 21 )
    )Cadaverico
```

To turn this into a single query, I would use McNets' solution. However, there is a solution that looks more like what you were going for.

You can `JOIN` the two queries. Since each of the separate queries will return only one row, a CROSS JOIN (which matches each row in the first dataset to each row in the second [with a count of M rows in the first and N in the second, the results are M*N rows]) will work fine (1 * 1 = 1).  First, we simplify the original two queries, and give the results the names you gave the two queries:

```
select sum(vit_codigotiposexames) as Corpo_Delito
  from tb_vitima
 where vit_codigotiposexames in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,22 )
;
select sum(vit_codigotiposexames) as Cadaverico
  from tb_vitima
 where vit_codigotiposexames  = 21
;
```

Then, we turn the queries into subqueries, and join them:

```
select Corpo_Delito, Cadaverico
  from (select sum(vit_codigotiposexames) as Corpo_Delito
          from tb_vitima
         where vit_codigotiposexames in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,22 )
       ) sq1
       CROSS JOIN -- This can just be a comma, but this make the intent clearer when you look at the code in the future.
       (select sum(vit_codigotiposexames) as Cadaverico
          from tb_vitima
         where vit_codigotiposexames  = 21
       ) sq2
;
```

Like I said, I would use McNets' solution, but hopeful this helps you understand why what you first tried didn't work as planned.